Non-overlapping, non-stacked area plots or non-branching, non-constant quantity flow diagrams
Considering visualization for data over a small number of timepoints and a large number of series, in this case:
day |  a |  b |  c |  d |  e |  f
  0 |  2 |  4 |  2 |  0 |  1 |  3
 90 |  4 |  2 |  3 |  1 |  0 |  1
180 |  4 |  2 |  2 |  4 |  2 |  2

Bar and line charts do not work well due to the size of the set, grouping by timepoint does not allow for easy comparisons across series and vice versa. The stacked area and stacked column charts are a natural fit that allows for comparing both, however at small numbers of X axis points (in this case 3), and as data points near zero, both get distorted:

One can calculate "filler" data to align the series horizontally:
     day |    |  a |    |  b |     |  c   |     |  d |     |  e |     |  f
midpoint |    |  2 |    |  7 |     | 11.5 |     | 16 |     | 20 |     | 23.5
       0 |  1 |  2 |  2 |  4 | 1.5 |  2   | 3.5 |  0 | 3.5 |  1 | 1.5 |  3
      90 |  0 |  4 |  2 |  2 | 2   |  3   | 2.5 |  1 | 3.5 |  0 | 3   |  1
     180 |  0 |  4 |  2 |  2 | 2.5 |  2   | 1.5 |  4 | 1   |  2 | 1.5 |  2

and this improves the clarity:

And an area plot can be additionally improved by adding coordinates for spacing along the X axis:
     day |    |  a |    |  b |     |  c   |     |  d |     |  e |     |  f
midpoint |    |  2 |    |  7 |     | 11.5 |     | 16 |     | 20 |     | 23.5
       0 |  1 |  2 |  2 |  4 | 1.5 |  2   | 3.5 |  0 | 3.5 |  1 | 1.5 |  3
      10 |  1 |  2 |  2 |  4 | 1.5 |  2   | 3.5 |  0 | 3.5 |  1 | 1.5 |  3
      80 |  0 |  4 |  2 |  2 | 2   |  3   | 2.5 |  1 | 3.5 |  0 | 3   |  1
     100 |  0 |  4 |  2 |  2 | 2   |  3   | 2.5 |  1 | 3.5 |  0 | 3   |  1
     170 |  0 |  4 |  2 |  2 | 2.5 |  2   | 1.5 |  4 | 1   |  2 | 1.5 |  2
     180 |  0 |  4 |  2 |  2 | 2.5 |  2   | 1.5 |  4 | 1   |  2 | 1.5 |  2


The last of these starts to resemble a flow diagram such as a Sankey or parallel set diagram, though it does not have input and output streams and just changes in magnitude. It also resembles a violin chart, though the data is tied to x axis timepoints and the widths are not probability distributions. It is simply a parallel area plot - not stacked, not overlapping, and not bound to 100%.
Is there a name for this parallel area plot?
Is there a visualization method for this parallel area plot in R or Python (ggplot2 or otherwise) outside of calculating the filler data manually and then hiding it from view?

I don't know of a name for the final plot you created. But why not just use lines? 6 overlapping lines should be OK to read.

But in ggplot, you could make area plots and facet on the 6 groups. Then you'd have 6 area plots, each with one time series, each in its own facet, and you wouldn't have to manually calculate & hide the filler data.

@civilstat - The data set in my use case is 20 series deep, but even in this the line version would have a lot of clutter due to small whole numbers on the Y axis. The best option is honestly probably a heat map or the area plots faceted, yes.

Small multiples with lines seems like it would work well with 20. Though 20 doesn't seem too many and a single line chart might be fine as well.

Can you add an example dataset? If you use R, the dput() command works well for this.
